# Why does log4j message produce timestamps in UTC?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

The following log4j pattern layout

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} | %-5p | %-35.35c{1} | %m%n" />
</layout>
```

produces timestamps in UTC instead of local time zone. Why is that?

`LANG` on this unix system is `en_US.iso885915`. Typing `date` into the shell produces a date with the correct (local) time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, that the problem is in fact, that JVM doesn't use the OS TimeZone, but has it's own property to store it.

It can be set via JVM parameters, for example:

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Sofia
```

And by the way, it's possible to set TZ in log4j pattern (as part of %d pattern), if you use [Apache Extras for log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/), like this:

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT-4} | %-5p | %-35.35c{1} | %m%n" />
```